# Connect to Teamviewer inside a VM

Tags: virtualbox, remote-access, ipad, display-resolution

here is my scenario;

1. I installed a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit as a virtual machine using Virtualbox.
2. installed latest updates and guest additions
3. Install TeamViewer (official, latest .deb file from teamviewer.com
4. from my iPad, I connected to my Ubuntu VM using the same setting I use for Windows guests.
5. Ubuntu screen resolution never fits my iPad screen, and I either have a very low resolution, or a fairly good one with about the lower third of my screen got black !

What should I do with my Ubuntu installation?

notes:
both Windows and Ubuntu guests are having the same VM display settings, and the same TeamViewer settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue got resolved after reverting to native drivers (no guest additions)